# Canvas Clipping Save and Restore

Tags: canvas, save, restore, clip

We have a Canvas that uses 5 clipping areas (for front and back view). 
We need to save the entire canvas in session and restore it when user navigates back to the page. 
So far, we have not found a way to save the state of clip and restore it.
Looking forward to inputs.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is an outline of how to save and restore clipping regions on html canvas.**

Start with this outline and post a new question if you run into coding problems.

**Html canvas clipping involves:**

- Executing the path commands which define the clipping path.
- Doing the clip with `context.clip()`
- If more than a single clip is required, you must wrap each clip inside a `context.save` and `context.restore` pair.
- The transformation related commands that might be used to create clips are: `save, setTransform, transform, translate, rotate, scale, restore`
- The path drawing commands that might be used to create clips are: `beginPath, moveTo, arc, quadraticCurveTo, bezierCurveTo, lineTo, rect, arcTo, closePath`
- And the command that causes clipping is: `clip`

**To save and restore the clips** you must save and later re-execute all the clipping path related context commands (and their arguments).

- Issue the original commands (with arguments) that create the clipping paths.
- Save those commands (and arguments) in a format that can be serialized and stored.
- It's up to you to decide which format to use to store the commands. JSON is a common format used to save javascript arrays (like commands & arguments). You can create an easily convert javascript arrays and objects into a string using `JSON.stringify`.
- It's up to you to decide where the serialized commands will be stored. Common places to store serialized commands are:  a database, localStorage, session state, etc.
- Later, when the user navigates back to the page, you must fetch the saved JSON and "rehydrate" the commands (and arguments) using `JSON.parse`.
- Execute the saved clipping path commands (and arguments) and call `context.clip()` to recreate the same clipping as originally done.

**A framework for these tasks might involve creating a `PathObject` "class".**

This new `PathObject` class should be able to:

- Accepts & store all the original clipping path commands (and arguments).
- Play (re-execute) the stored clipping commands on the context.
- Serialize its stored commands to JSON.
- Accept a JSON string (containing serialized commands & arguments) and restore the PathObject's state.
- Reissue the clipping path commands necessary to recreate the same clips that were originally created.

**The `PathObject` might contain these properties and methods:**

*Properties:*

- commands[], arguments[] with each sequentially paired command & argument being a single step in creating the clipping path (see above for which path related commands you must record).

*Methods:*

- A `PathObject` method (function) corresponding to each of the path commands. Each function simply accepts the arguments related to that command and does `commands.push` and `arguments.push` for each of the accepted arguments.

  ```
  // when myPathObject.moveTo(x,y) is called...

  // store moveTo in the commands array
  commands.push('moveTo');

  // store x,y (as an array) into the arguments array
  arguments.push([x,y]);
  ```
- A method to execute all the stored path commands on the context.

  ```
  for(var i=0;i<commands.length;i++){
      context[commands[i]].apply(context, args[i]);            
  }
  ```
- A method to serialize the accumulated commands to a JSON string using

  ```
  var commandsAndArgs={
      commands:commands,
      args:args
  }
  return(JSON.stringify(commandsAndArgs));
  ```
- A method to deserialize the JSON string using

  ```
  var j=JSON.parse(json);
  this.commands=j.commands;
  this.args=j.args;
  ```